# Accessing core-data present inside a framework from another ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, ios-frameworks

I developed a framework called XYZControls.framework with XYZ.sqlite and XYZAppDelegate.m in it. I developed another ios app ABC by including XYZControls.framework. But when i try to save data inside XYZ.sqlite from ABC application, app is crashing with below errors.

```
  -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:    [AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'
```

Also how to access **managedObjectContext,parentContext and writerObjectContexts** of XYZ.sqlite from ABC application and how to save data to XYZ.sqlite present in XYZControls.framework from ABC application?

Answer (score 0):

XYZControls.framework appears to assume that the app delegate is the place to go to find the managed object context. That's a common pattern, but should not be assumed by a framework. You'll have to modify XYZControls to accept a MOC location that you pass it, or modify your app delegate to match the framework's assumptions.

Comment: How to modify my app delegate to match framework's assumptions. Should i create separate MOCs for my framework and appdelegate? Can u share piece of code or example regarding this.